# compare string to string list in c

Tags: c, string

in my C application, I have a string which I want to compare to a list of strings in my application. the list of strings can be hardcoded in my C application.

1. what is the best way to define the list of strings in my application?
2. what is the best way to compare the string in my application to the list of strings?

Answer (score 6):

I you are after efficiency, you should use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), it will give you `O(|S|)` search time to match your input string to the given set of strings. [where |S| is the length of the input string]

If you are after quick coding, just store the strings in a predefined `char*[]`, and iterate over it with `strcmp()`

Comment: Note that basic tries have very poor cache performance (a cache miss per character in this case), which would probably make it inferior to the simple sort-and-binary-search approach described in other answers. If the list of strings being compared against is really huge, my advice would be to use a cache-tuned data structure as JudySL (http://judy.sourceforge.net/doc/JudySL_3x.htm), or if that's not an option, a (reasonably sparse) hash table.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "compare a string to a list of strings"? The two are different kinds of "objects", they are not obviously comparable.

How does the string `"372"` compare to the list of strings `{ "12, "42", "-11", "372" }`?

If you mean "look for a string in a list of strings", then the best bet would be to sort the list, then use binary-search to quickly check if the candidate is present.

A list of strings is easily represented in C as an array of character pointers, `char *strings[]`. You can use `qsort()` to sort, and `bsearch()` to search.

Comment: if the string is "372" then my code should return true for the listof strring you've provided.

Comment: "A list of strings is easily represented in C as an array of character pointers" - although in this case you could instead sort the strings first by length, and then lexicographically. Keep an index of the first string of each length. That can all be done at build-time, since the strings are known. Then you can do a binary search into an array containing the actual string data, not just pointers to each string. So there's a bit less overhead and hopefully slightly better cache performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want excessive speed, and you're willing to use extra tools, you could consider [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/). Given a list of strings, it works out a very fast inclusion test based on a hash function, and spits out the C code for it.